# Common strategy in handling concurrent global 'inventory' updates

Tags: database, architecture, scalability

To give a simplified example:

I have a database with one table: names, which has 1 million records each containing a common boy or girl's name, and more added every day.

I have an application server that takes as input an http request from parents using my website 'Name Chooser' . With each request, I need to pick up a name from the db and return it, and then NOT give that name to another parent. The server is concurrent so can handle a high volume of requests, and yet have to respect "unique name per request" and still be high available.

What are the major components and strategies for an architecture of this use case?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you have two operations: **Adding a name** and **Choosing a name**.

I have couple of questions:

- **Qustion 1:** Do parents *choose names* only or do they also *add names*?
- **Question 2** If they *add names*, doest that mean that when *a name is added* it should also be marked as *already chosen*?

Assuming that you don't want to make all name selection requests to wait for one another (by locking of queueing them):

One solution to resolve concurrency in case of **choosing a name** only is to use [Optimistic offline lock](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/optimisticOfflineLock.html).

The most common implementation to this is to add a version field to your table and increment this version when you mark a name as **chosen**. You will need DB support for this, but most databases offer a mechanism for this. MongoDB adds a version field to the documents by default. For a RDBMS (like SQL) you have to add this field yourself.

You havent specified what technology you are using, so I will give an example using pseudo code for an SQL DB. For MongoDB you can check how the DB makes these checks for you.

```
NameRecord {
  id,
  name,
  parentID,
  version,
  isChosen,

  function chooseForParent(parentID) {

    if(this.isChosen){
      throw Error/Exception;
    }

    this.parentID = parentID
    this.isChosen = true;
    this.version++;
  }
}

NameRecordRepository {

  function getByName(name) { ... }

  function save(record) {

    var oldVersion = record.version - 1;

    var query = "UPDATE records SET ..... 
                 WHERE id = {record.id} AND version = {oldVersion}";

    var rowsCount = db.execute(query);

    if(rowsCount == 0) {
      throw ConcurrencyViolation
    }
  }
}

// somewhere else in an object or module or whatever...

function chooseName(parentID, name) {

   var record = NameRecordRepository.getByName(name);

   record.chooseForParent(parentID);

   NameRecordRepository.save(record);
}
```

Before whis object is saved to the DB a version comparison must be performed. SQL provides a way to execute a query based on some condition and return the row count of affected rows. In our case we check if the version in the Database is the same as the old one before update. If it's not, that means that someone else has updated the record.

In this simple case you can even remove the version field and use the isChosen flag in your SQL query like this:

```
    var query = "UPDATE records SET ..... 
                 WHERE id = {record.id} AND isChosend = false";
```

When adding a new name to the database you will need a Unique constrant that will solve concurrenty issues.